# Magento 2.2.4 Order Confirmation Mail Not Receive

Tags: magento2.2.4

Magento 2.2.4 Order Confirmation Email Not Receive by Customer 
and Newsletter Emails Received by Subscriber Successfully

Answer (score 1):

Install Following Extension in magento website 
i have use this extension in magento 2.2.4 and my issue is resolved 
https://github.com/sashas777/bug-from-email

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled "*Asynchronous sending*" in your settings "*Stores > Configuration > Sales > Sales Emails > General Settings > Asynchronous sending*", make sure your cron is running correctly.
You can make Magento send emails instantly by disabling this option.

This issue has been discussed further in https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/15476